# Вопрос по тернарному оператору

Tags: python, тернарный-оператор

```
count = 0
for i in range(int(input()),0,-1):
    count += i if i %3==0 or i%5==0 else count += 0
print(count)
```

```
count += i if i %3==0 or i%5==0 else count += 0
                                           ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Подскажите в чём ошибка

Comment: В `A if B else C` на месте `A`, `B`, `C` допустимы только выражения. `count += 0` - не выражение, а оператор. Если вы возразите, что `count += i` работает, то он работает совсем не так как вам хочется. `count += 1 if i %3==0 or i%5==0 else 0` - вот это сработает как вам нужно.

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
count += (i if (i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0) else  0)
```